# Different behavior of Windows Store and WPF app designers for the same view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, designer

I am using MVVP pattern to share most of the code between Windows Store (aka Metro) and WPF applications. One of the controls has its visibility controlled by state of a view model member:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsServiceSelected, 
            Mode=TwoWay, 
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
```

A property "IsServiceSelected" is defined on a view model behind the data context. I have a fake view model with some data only used by the designer. The property IsServiceSelected in this fake model is evaludated to "true" (there is no member field for this property, it's computed based on other data). This works fine for a WPF application, I see that the control's visibility is Visible. But for the Windows Store app the control's visibility is always Collapsed at design-time, only at runtime it's evaluated correctly.

If I extend XAML definition with **ConverterParameter=True**, the control shows up, so it's obviously the value of "IsServiceSelected" that is not evaluated correctly. But what is strange is that I share the same code (in a portable class library) for my models, view models and that particular fake view model, so it should be evaluated to the same value on different platforms. But it does not.

**UPDATE** False alarm, the problem was with my code. Fixed.

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` of the page the control is in?

Comment: DataContext is set in the same way both for WPF and Store app, using d:DataContext={d:DesignInstance Type=fakemodeltype etc...}

Answer (score 1):

Different behavior is probably caused by the converter, since setting `ConverterParameter=True` makes it work in Windows Store apps as well. You obviously can't be using the same the same converter both in WPF and Windows Store apps since they have to implement a different interface.

Compare both implementations and you should be able to spot the difference. For Windows Store apps implementation in particular check how `parameter` argument of `Convert` method is used. Setting it to `true` seems to change the return value.

Comment: Hm, in my case it's it works if I set ConverterParameter=False. Obviously it's IsServiceSelected property that is not set, I just have to figure out why it's set in the same code in WPF case (I don't reuse converters but reuse view models).

Comment: @VagifAbilov In runtime it works fine, even without `ConverterParameter` set?

Comment: Yes Damir, in runtime it works fine event without parameter, and in design time it works fine only for WPF (.NET 4.5) app, but not for Windows Store.

Comment: @VagifAbilov I'd love to see a small sample repoducing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to extract small code portion and post it.

Comment: I spent some time reproducing this issue on a smaller example, and when it became small enough, the problem went away. That was all my fault: I used additional framework (MvvmCross) in my code and made a mistake in data binding that caused this problem.
Sorry for the false alarm, and thanks for your help.